# public method + c# + fluent nhibernate + asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, methods, fluent-nhibernate

I want to reduce the code duplication and have created a public method to get all the categories from the database (this is in my repository for the categoryclass). i want to do this public because i retieve the categoires in multiple pages. When i populate a DDL i just want to call categories as the datasource.

It look something like:

```
public IList<Category> categories()
{ //code to fetch the categories
  return categories;
}
```

But in my code-behind file i can't call categories();
I have referenced the repositories path.

How should i use the public method to be used in multiple pages from my repositories?

Comment: When you say you can't call it is that as in it just won't compile because the reference isn't valid or it fails at runtime or somethign else...?

Answer (score 0):

I think you forget about `add reference`.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a C# issue - probably nothing to do with Fluent NHibernate.

Maybe you forgot to add the parenthesis when you call the method? e.g.

categories, instead of categories()

It would help if you showed more of your code - like the declaration of the categories member, and where you are trying to call it.